# Generate more rows if there is a difference between two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on some reports from MS Project Server and found this oddity:

For some obscure reason, whenever you appoint to **the same task with the same amount of time in consecutive days**, instead of creating an entry for each appointment, the application updates the start date and the finish date fields on database, leaving only one entry for that task, but with a range between the dates.

If the amount of time appointed to the task in consecutive days are different, then there will be created one entry per appointment.

(Yes, I know, it's kind of confusing. I don't even know how to explain this better).

I want to know if it is somehow possible to generate more rows within SQL statement whenever there is a difference between the start and the finish date, **one for each day in the range**.

This is the query I have right now, I already can tell which rows have this date difference, but I don't know what I can do next.

```
select 
        r.WRES_ID, r.RES_NAME, PROJ_NAME, p.WPROJ_ID, TASK_NAME, WWORK_VALUE, WWORK_START, WWORK_FINISH,
        datediff(d, WWORK_START, WWORK_FINISH) + 1 AS work_days
    from MSP_WEB_RESOURCES r
    join
    MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS a on a.WRES_ID = r.WRES_ID
    join
    MSP_WEB_PROJECTS p on p.WPROJ_ID = a.WPROJ_ID
    join
    MSP_WEB_WORK w on w.WASSN_ID = a.WASSN_ID
    where RES_NAME = 'HenriqueBarcelos'
    and WWORK_TYPE = 1
    and WWORK_VALUE > 0
    and WWORK_FINISH between '2014-01-27' and '2014-01-31'
    order by WWORK_FINISH DESC
```

I know I could do this at the application level, but I was wondering if I could just do it within the database itself.

Thank's in advance.

### Edit:

These are my current results:

```
WRES_ID | RES_NAME         | TASK_NAME               | WWORK_VALUE   | WWORK_START         | WWORK_FINISH        | work_days
--------+------------------+-------------------------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------
382     | HenriqueBarcelos | Outsourcing Initiatives | 60000.000000  | 2014-01-30 00:00:00 | 2014-01-30 00:00:00 | 1
382     | HenriqueBarcelos | Internal Training       | 289800.000000 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00 | 1
382     | HenriqueBarcelos | Outsourcing Initiatives | 120000.000000 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00 | 2014-01-29 00:00:00 | 1
382     | HenriqueBarcelos | Outsourcing Initiatives | 60000.000000  | 2014-01-27 00:00:00 | 2014-01-28 00:00:00 | 2
382     | HenriqueBarcelos | Infrastructure (TI)     | 120000.000000 | 2014-01-27 00:00:00 | 2014-01-27 00:00:00 | 1
```

Notice that the second last register has a range of 2 days. In deed, there are 2 appointments, one on Jan 27th and other on 28th.

What I want to do is expand this and return one entry per day in this case.

Comment: Can you append your current results to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it's not very elegant. First you need a function that will expand the date range into sequence of dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_Expand(@start DATE, @end DATE)
RETURNS TABLE   
AS
RETURN
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT @start AS dt

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) FROM cte WHERE dt < @end
)
SELECT dt FROM cte
```

Then use that in your query with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT /* your columns */, x.dt
FROM /* your joins */
CROSS APPLY ufn_Expand(WWORK_START, WWORK_FINISH) x
```

Comment: I'm getting and error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.`.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos what version of SQL Server?

Comment: CTEs are around since 2005, this shouldn't be a problem. A quick sample  on SqlFiddle [http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8033a/2/0](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8033a/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a numbers table (nice and set-based, yum!)

```
SELECT start_date
     , end_date
     , DateDiff(dd, start_date, end_date) + 1 As number_of_days --rows to display
FROM   your_table
 INNER
  JOIN dbo.numbers
    ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND DateDiff(dd, start_date, end_date) + 1
```

Use your favourite search engine to find a numbers table script. [Here's one I made earlier](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/dbo.numbers%20&%20dbo.calendar.sql).

*As an aside: if you remove the `+1`s you just modify the join to be between zero and the DateDiff() - I added the +1s as I thought it might be clearer!*

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to create tables.

Comment: I could do it with a temp table. Almost there, I already have an entry for each appointment. Now I just need to increment the date for each entry, because they are coming the same.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos is there a maximum number of days? If you need a numbers table on the fly try: `SELECT DISTINCT number FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type = 'P' AND number <= 255`

Comment: I could have, but can't guarantee it. This issue is solved with the temp table, what I don't know how to do is to increment the dates for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this from another perspective. You don't really want a row per each worked day. What you really need it's the number of worked days, multiplied by the reported worked time. Something like this:

```
(dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_VALUE / 60000) * (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH) + 1)
```

however, this creates an issue. Let's say you want a given period. If you use the WWORK_START and WWORK_FINISH dates for your report, you need to be careful to include all the work with only some days inside the period. Something like this will do it:

```
DECLARE @InitDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;

SET @InitDate = '2016/06/01';
SET @EndDate = '2016/07/01';

--Full list of tasks
SELECT  dbo.MSP_WEB_RESOURCES.RES_NAME AS Name, dbo.MSP_WEB_PROJECTS.PROJ_NAME AS Project, 
        dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_VALUE / 60000 AS ReportedWork,
        CASE
            WHEN WWORK_START < @InitDate THEN DATEDIFF(day, @InitDate, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH) + 1 --If the task started before the start of the period
            WHEN WWORK_FINISH > DATEDIFF(day,-1,@EndDate) THEN DATEDIFF(day, WWORK_START, DATEDIFF(day,-1,@EndDate)) + 1 --if the task ended after the end of the period
            ELSE DATEDIFF(day, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH) + 1 --All tasks with start and end date inside the period
        END AS RepeatedDays,        
        CASE
            WHEN WWORK_START < @InitDate THEN (dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_VALUE / 60000) * (DATEDIFF(day, @InitDate, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH) + 1)
            WHEN WWORK_FINISH > DATEDIFF(day,-1,@EndDate) THEN (dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_VALUE / 60000) * (DATEDIFF(day, WWORK_START, DATEDIFF(day,-1,@EndDate)) + 1)
            ELSE (dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_VALUE / 60000) * (DATEDIFF(day, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START, dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH) + 1)
        END AS ActualWork,
        dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START, 
        dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH
FROM    dbo.MSP_WEB_RESOURCES INNER JOIN
        dbo.MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS INNER JOIN
        dbo.MSP_WEB_PROJECTS ON dbo.MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS.WPROJ_ID = dbo.MSP_WEB_PROJECTS.WPROJ_ID INNER JOIN
        dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK ON dbo.MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS.WASSN_ID = dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WASSN_ID ON 
        dbo.MSP_WEB_RESOURCES.WRES_ID = dbo.MSP_WEB_ASSIGNMENTS.WRES_ID
WHERE   (dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_TYPE = 1) AND 
        (
            @InitDate BETWEEN dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START and dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH OR
            DATEADD(day,-1,@EndDate) BETWEEN dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START and dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH OR
            (dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START >= @InitDate) AND
            (dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_FINISH < @EndDate)
        )
ORDER BY dbo.MSP_WEB_WORK.WWORK_START;
```